# Why is python3.4 trying to load python2.7 TensorFlow package on RedHat7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have both python2.7 and python3.4 installed on my RedHat7 machine. I installed `tensorflow` for both versions.

P2.7 seems to be working fine:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']
>>> import tensorflow
>>>
```

For p3.4 I am getting:

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Jan 26 2016, 02:25:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site; site.getsitepackages()
['/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/site-python']
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
>>>
```

Why is p3 trying to grab p2 packages?

**UPDATE #1:**

- `sys.path` produced `['', '/usr/lib64/python34.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.4', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.4/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages']`
- `PYTHONPATH` is undefined

**UPDATE #2**: As Martijn suggested I ran

```
python3 -v -c 'import tensorflow' > ~/log.txt 2>&1
```

and saw the following block

```
...
import 'types' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fd5b3e7e8d0>
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fd5b3f4bba8>
# code object from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
# could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc': PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
# wrote '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
# /usr/lib64/python3.4/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-34.pyc matches /usr/lib64/python3.4/__future__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib64/python3.4/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-34.pyc'
import '__future__' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fd5b3ea04e0>
# code object from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py
# could not create '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc': PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
# wrote '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
...
```

I ran the following commands that got rid of these errors:

```
sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__
sudo chmod -R ugo+rX /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/
```

BUT I am still getting the following:

```
import 'imp' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7fb372a1f320>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
# clear builtins._
# clear sys.path
```

**UPDATE #3:** The commands that I asked my sysadmin to run to install TF for p3.4 were pulled directly from the TF install page:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.4
export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Is it possible that `pip3` is somehow out of whack and points to p2.7 instead of p3.4? That said, I think part of the TF install is installing `numpy` and I am not getting any errors when importing it into p3.4, so there might be something else going on.

**UPDATE #4:** I've asked our sysadmin (who originally installed TF for me) to run the `python3 -v -c 'import tensorflow'` command on his side. His result is different from mine: python3 pulls the right libraries and TF loads fine. Here's an excerpt from my log:

```
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
```

And here's from his:

```
# /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
# /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc matches /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py
# code object from '/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-34.pyc'
```

`PYTHONPATH` is defined neither for him nor for me. So why is python working differently for us?

Comment: There are no symlinks in any of the directories listed in `sys.path`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I ran `ls -lR` on all of them. Got a long list, but I am not seeing any links there.

Comment: Next thing to try: `python3 -v -c 'import tensorflow'`. This may provide clues.

Comment: How did you install python 3.4? How did you install tensorflow?

Comment: What is `/usr/lib/site-python`? Looks like a symlink to me.

Comment: @Dunes it is not on `sys.path` so it doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @larsks I installed p3.4 using `sudo yum install python34`. I had to ask our sysadmin to install TF for me using the "pip installation" instructions on TF's webpage since I don't have enough rights on this machine even though I am a sudo'er. Before that I tried, without luck, to make a local install of TF

Comment: @IZ It seems like the python 2.7 version of tensorflow was installed instead of the 3.4 version.